# The ratio that the orthocenter divides an altitude into

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, ratio

In [a book](https://trove.nla.gov.au/work/10051067?selectedversion=NBD10151446) I'm reading, it claimed that the orthocenter $(H)$ of any triangle (apart from right) divided an altitude into this ratio:
[image]
$$\frac{AH}{HD}=\frac{\cos A}{\cos B \cos C}$$
I have tried and failed to find a proof of this property, can someone provide a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For acute-angled triangle we obtain: $$\frac{AH}{HD}=\frac{\frac{AE}{\cos\measuredangle HAE}}{BD\tan\measuredangle HBD}=\frac{\frac{c\cos\alpha}{\sin\gamma}}{c\cos\beta\cot\gamma}=\frac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\beta\cos\gamma}$$

Comment: I'm assuming this works for obtuse-angled triangles if $AH$ and $HD$ are directed, because one of $\cos\alpha , \cos\beta ,\cos\gamma$ is negative.